# Magento 2 How can I get selected swatch options on wishlist page?

Tags: customer-account, wishlist, magento2.3.2, configurable-swatches

I am trying to get selected swatches color, the size on wishlist page in Magento 2.3

If I add a simple product in wishlist then attribute value is showing but when I am trying to get selected options from the configurable product then the option's value is not showing.

Can anyone help to do this?

Comment: have you checked after re-indexing the products.

Comment: yes, I have checked. but still same